# Mapping Appointment Entity for Data Migration in Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2015

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, lookup, dynamics-crm-2015

I need to migrate data from CRM 2011 to CRM 2015 for different entities. I am using scribe insight for this purpose. I am stuck with the the migration of different entities belonging to Activities like Appointment, Letter, Fax, etc.
If its a normal lookup field i would have used something like

`DBLOOKUP(S25,"CRM 2015","Lookup Entity name","Matching field","Primary key")`

There is a field type named 'Party List' which is lookup to multiple entities. How do I map this? So that I can easily migrate data from 2011 to 2015?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're saying you want to migrate Activity records from CRM2011 to CRM2015. I've done something very similar from CRM4 to 2011, using Scribe Insight.

PartyList is a composite field, built from ActivityParty records. You don't write to it directly.
An ActivityParty record links an Activity (eg, email, task) to a Party (eg, account, contact, user, lead).

The sequence of events is:

Migrate Party records (contacts, accounts etc).
For each Activity in CRM 2011
  Create an Activity in CRM 2015
  For each ActivityParty belonging to the Activity in CRM2011
    Create an ActivityParty in CRM2015
  Set the status of the CRM2015 Activity to that of the CRM2011 Activity.

Some points to note:

1. ActivityParty records are somewhat special in CRM. They don't support all messages. Specifically, the can't be updated - only created or deleted.
2. You can only set the status of the Activity after you've added all the activity parties. CRM will generate an error if you try to add an activityparty to a completed activity.

Hope this helps

Mike

Comment: Hey Mike I am still stuck up with the migration for activityparties. Can we have a skype session whenever you are available?

Answer (score -1):

Based on your DBLookup code you use Scribe for migration. I'm not an expert in Scribe so I would suggest to use search engine to find relevant information. Try to use [this search](https://www.google.co.th/?gws_rd=cr&ei=ZZX1VMyiBI3muQSI6oDgDQ#q=scribe%20activityparty%20mapping).